# Subclass of SQLiteDatabaseHelper throws NullpointerException when calls getReadebleDatabase()

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-database

I have a subclass of `SQLiteDatabaseOpenHelper` called `DatabaseSuper` which overrides `onCreate` and `onUpdate` methods.  `DatabaseController` class is the subclass of `DatabaseSuper` which intended to implement all the application specific database actions.

My problem is, when I am calling `getReadableDatabase()` in a method in `DatabaseController` class, it thorws  a `Nullpointer exceptio`n.
But if I am pass a `SQLiteDatabase` object as a parameter to that method which taken from the base class `(DatabaseSuper)`, no exception is throw.

**Method**

```
public String sendDate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    //SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();                 *line 1*

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select date from todo", null);
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String date = cursor.getString(0);  
        stringBuffer.append(date + ":");
    }
    cursor.close();
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

**Calling method from activity class**

```
String data = dataControllerObject.sendDate(new DatabaseSuper(this).getReadableDatabase());
```

**Error**

```
06-18 04:28:50.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5147): 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 04:28:50.239: 
E/AndroidRuntime(5147): 
java.lang.RuntimeException:Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dolist/com.example.dolist.SearchListView}:
java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 04:28:50.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5147):
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-18 04:28:50.239:

E/AndroidRuntime(5147):     
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-18 04:28:50.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5147):
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-18 04:28:50.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5147):
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-18 04:28:50.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5147):
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-18 04:28:50.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5147):
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-18 04:28:50.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5147):
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-18 04:28:50.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5147):
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 04:28:50.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5147):
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 04:28:50.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5147):
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-18 04:28:50.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5147):
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-18 04:28:50.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5147):
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 04:28:50.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5147):
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 04:28:50.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5147):
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
06-18 04:28:50.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5147):
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
06-18 04:28:50.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5147):
at com.example.dolist.DataController.sendDate(DataController.java:37)
06-18 04:28:50.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5147):
at com.example.dolist.SearchListView.onCreate(SearchListView.java:34)
06-18 04:28:50.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5147):
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-18 04:28:50.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5147):
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-18 04:28:50.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5147):
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-18 04:28:50.239: E/AndroidRuntime(5147):
... 11 more
```

Comment: Use `this.getReadableDatabase();` instead of `getReadableDatabase();`

Answer (score 0):

The `Context` that gets passed to `SQLiteOpenHelper` in constructor is `null`.

In the calling part

```
String data = dataControllerObject.sendDate(new DatabaseSuper().getReadableDatabase());
```

you're not actually passing in any `Context` - `new DatabaseSuper()` without any arguments. The `SQLiteOpenHelper` superclass constructor needs one so you're probably passing in an explicit `null`. For detailed help, post your constructor code.

Comment: Sorry, i have already passed context argument to the constructor, but forgot to mention here.

Comment: Even then the exception is about a bad `Context` getting passed to `SQLiteOpenHelper`.